# defining and calling custom AJAX function for multiple pages not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, user-defined-functions

I've created an AJAX request that will load my about page info dynamically. I am trying to do this for all my pages while keeping my code DRY. So I'm trying to create a function with it, but can't figure out why it's not working.

About page AJAX request that's working-AJAX About.html

```
        $('#about-button').on('click', function() {
          $('body section').hide(),
          $(this).closest('nav').find('.active-page').removeClass('active-page'),
          $(this).closest('nav').find('#about-button').addClass('active-page')

          $.ajax('about.html', {
            success: function(response) {
              $('.about-page').html(response).slideDown()
            },
            error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
              $('body').html("<h5> 'Error: ' + errorType + ' with message ' + errorMessage </h5>")
            },
            timeout: 3000
          }); 
        });
```

Custom function to be used for all pages...

```
        function pageCall (ajaxButton, ajaxUrl, ajaxPage) {
        ajaxButton.on('click', function() {
        $('body section').hide(),
        $(this).closest('nav').find('.active-page').removeClass('active-page'),

            $(this).closest('nav').find(ajaxButton).addClass('active-page')

        $.ajax(ajaxUrl, {
          success: function(response) {
            ajaxPage.html(response).slideDown()
          },
          error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
            $('body').html("<h5> 'Error: ' + errorType + ' with message ' + errorMessage </h5>")
          },
          timeout: 3000
          }); 
        });
      };
```

A couple different ways i'm trying to call the function... none of which cause any errors to be logged in the console, but the about page content is not loaded...

Attempt 1:

```
        pageCall ('#about-button', 'about.html','.about-page');
```

Attempt 2:

```
     var aboutAjax = pageCall ('#about-button', 'about.html', '.about-page');
```

Attempt 3:

```
      function pageCall (ajaxButton, ajaxUrl, ajaxPage) {
          var ajaxButton = '#about-button'
          var ajaxUrl = 'about.html'
          var ajaxPage = '.about-page'
      }

     aboutAjax;
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: *Where* are you **defining** and **calling** the function? If it's defined in a closure you won't be able to access outside of that closure.

Comment: Well first thing i see is  pageCall ('#about-button', 'about.html','.about-page'); Your're passing in string but expect to attach event handler to it : ajaxButton.on('click', function()

Comment: Same problem here: ajaxPage.html(response).slideDown(). ajaxPage is probably a string here as well.

Comment: So I changed the pageCall to --
            pageCall ($('#about-button'), $('about.html'),$('.about-page'));

Now, it runs the first part of the function, clearing the previous page data (body section), but it doesn't load any of the about page info. I'm running this function call after defining it, to answer Adam's question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

```
    pageCall ($('#about-button'),'about.html',$('.about-page'));
```

the 'about.html' is supposed to be a string.

Thanks for your help guys!